# c++ LogFile Object Compile Errors

Tags: c++, string

I am making a log file object at the bottom is is .h and .cc

bellow is the error i get, please help

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "LogFile::log(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced
>   from:
>         TextDisplay::notify(int, int, Cell::CellType) in textdisplay.o
>         Floor::loadFloor(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, Player*) in
>   floor.o
>         Floor::isStairwaySet() in floor.o
>         Floor::getCellAtCoord(int, int) in floor.o
>         Floor::getPossibleSpots(Occupant*, int, int) in floor.o
>         Floor::getNearbyPlayer(int, int) in floor.o
>         Character::dealDamage(int) in character.o
>         ...   "LogFile::log(char const*)", referenced from:
>         CC3K::cleanUp() in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::startGame(Occupant::SpecificType, std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >) in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::step() in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::playerMove(CC3K::Command, CC3K::Direction) in cc3k.o
>         Floor::loadFloor(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, Player*) in
>   floor.o
>         Floor::notifyStairwayBeingSet(int, int) in floor.o
>         Cell::removeDeadOccupant() in cell.o
>         ...   "LogFile::dlog(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced
>   from:
>         Merchant::attackStep() in merchant.o   "LogFile::dlog(char const*)", referenced from:
>         Character::attack(Character&) in character.o
>         Merchant::attackStep() in merchant.o   "LogFile::getI()", referenced from:
>         CC3K::cleanUp() in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::startGame(Occupant::SpecificType, std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >) in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::step() in cc3k.o
>         CC3K::playerMove(CC3K::Command, CC3K::Direction) in cc3k.o
>         TextDisplay::notify(int, int, Cell::CellType) in textdisplay.o
>         Floor::loadFloor(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, Player*) in
>   floor.o
>         Floor::notifyStairwayBeingSet(int, int) in floor.o
>         ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

bellow is the some lines of code the error is talking about

```
LogFile::getI()->log("Error textdisplay.cc 77: Weird cellType given: " + to_string(cellType));
LogFile::getI()->log("Error floor.cc isStairwaySet() 141: Weird values for stairwayRow: " + to_string(stairwayRow) + " stairwayCol: " + to_string(stairwayCol));
```

.h

```
#ifndef __LOGFILE_H__
#define __LOGFILE_H__

#include <string>

class LogFile
{
    static LogFile *singleton;

    LogFile(std::string fileName);
    ~LogFile();

    int logNum;
    std::string fileName;

    static void cleanUp();

    public:

        enum Error {};
        //must be called before use, fileName to log too
        static LogFile *initInstance(std::string fileName);
        static LogFile *getI();

        void log(std::string error);
        void log(const char *error);
        void dlog(std::string error);
        void dlog(const char *error);
        bool hasLoged();
        int getNumLogs();
};

#include "logfile.h"
```

.cc

```
#include "logfile.h"
#include <ofstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

static LogFile *LogFile::singleton = NULL;

void LogFile::cleanUp()
{
    delete singleton;
}

LogFile::LogFile(std::string fileName): logNum(0), fileName(fileName){}

LogFile::~LogFile(){}

//must be called before use, fileName to log too
LogFile *LogFile::initInstance(std::string fileName)  //static
{
    if(singleton)
    {
        singleton->log("Error: logfile.cc initInstance() 19: Calling this function more than once is wrong implementation");
        return singleton;
    }else
    {
        singleton = new LogFile(fileName);      
#ifdef REPRAND
singleton->log("#define REPRAND");
#endif
#define DEBUG
singleton->log("#define DEBUG");
#endif  
        atexit(cleanUp)
        return singleton;
    }
}

LogFile *LogFile::getI() //static
{
    if(!singleton)
    {
        LogFile::getI()->log("Error: logfile.cc getInstance() 32: Calling getInstance() without having first called initInstance()");
    }else
    {
        return singleton;
    }
}

void LogFile::log(std::string error)
{
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(fileName.c_str(), ofstream::out | ofstream::app);

    ofs << error << endl;

    if(!ofs.good)
        LogFile::getI()->log("Error writeToFile() 47: output file stream is not good");

    logNum ++;
}

void LogFile::log(char *error)
{
    log(string(error));
}

void LogFile::dlog(std::string error)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
log(error);
#endif
}

void LogFile::dlog(char *error)
{
    dlog(string(error));
}

bool LogFile::hasLoged()
{
    return (logNum > 0);
}

int LogFile::getNumLogs()
{
    return logNum;
}
```

Comment: You need to go back and start over with your C++ reading. Then you might notice that member functions definitions needs to be scoped correctly, like e.g. `LogFile::log` and not just `log`.

Comment: How do you compile your source code? What ide do you use? Or do you write your own Makefile? Undefined symbol are linker errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  forgetting to add the file name into a make file

Answer (score 2):

```
void log(std::string error)
```

does not define the member function you want it to.  you have to say:

```
void LogFile::log(std::string error)
```

Your definition just defined a bare function called `log`, which is valid so the compiler didn't complain until linking.

Comment: i made this change and still same errors, see above edit

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class name in your method body declarations.

For example in your .cc instead of:

```
static LogFile *getI()
```

Write:

```
static LogFile* LogFile::getI()
```

Your log method body should look like:

```
void LogFile::Log(std::string error)
{
    ...
}
```

You have to do this for every method you have in LogFile class.

Next you have some ifdef macro and under it:

```
#define DEBUG
singleton->log("#define DEBUG");
#endif
```

This looks like a copy-paste error and there should be `#ifdef` instead of `#define`.

Comment: i made this change and still same errors, see above edit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a typo, but in your "log" method you have the following:

```
ofs << error); // Where does the ending paranthesis come from?
```

Without further looking, see if that fixes your error. :)

Comment: i made this change and still same errors, see above edit

Answer (score 0):

You are getting closer.  Hopefully you are not getting exact errors still, just a subset.

This definition:

```
void LogFile::log(std::string error)
```

now matches the declaration, but

```
void LogFile::log(char *error)
```

Is slightly different than the declared:

```
void log(const char *error);
```

The parameter types and return values have to match exactly.